# Looping array and inserting into database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to loop through the array and insert them into the database. When i check dd($request->users), it displays "NULL" but if i put dd($request->all()), the data array appears. Plus the code for controller below doesn't insert the data into the database. Thanks

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
      return{  
            users: [{
                username:'',
                password:'',
                phone:'',
                email:''
            }]
      }
    },
    methods:{
        addMoreData(){
            this.users.push({
                username: '', 
                password: '' , 
                email: '',
                phone:''
                });
        },
        deleteData(index){
            this.users.splice(index,1)  
        },
        submitData(){
         axios.post('/api/user', this.users)
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{   
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->all()); $i++) {
        data::create([
                'username'=>$request->username[$i],
                'password'=>$request->password[$i],
                'phone'=>$request->phone[$i],
                'email'=>$request->email[$i]
            ]);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

[Result for dd(request->all()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsQcf.jpg)

[Result for dd(request->users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N9LV.jpg)

Comment: First you need to variable for creating user. Like `$user = User::create([..])`. Can you write `dd($request->all())` and display result here?

Comment: @mare96 check the edit

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your case i think.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
   foreach($request->all() as $user){
      $u = User::create([
             'username'=>$user['username'],
             'password'=>$user['password'],
             'phone'=>$user['phone'],
             'email'=>$user['email']
      ])
     return ...
   }
}
```

But if you want to send users from frontend you will need to place users in new array named users.
Good luck.

Comment: i got this error "message: "Trying to get property 'username' of non-object
"

Answer (score 0):

If your data in this format as per your this image

[image]

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){   

    $users = $request->all();

    if(!empty($users)){
        foreach($users as $user){
           data::create($user);
        }
    }
}
```